# Convert double to 2 decimal places

Tags: java

I got a table column with decimal(18,2) data type as price in database. When I create a product, let's say I enter $15.50, it's stored as 15.50 in database. But however, when I try to retrieve the value from database as Double and display in table, it shows 15.5. This is how I set up my price in table:

```
 TableColumn prodPriceCol = new TableColumn("PRICE ($)");
 prodPriceCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, Double>("prodPrice"));
 prodPriceCol.setMinWidth(100);
```

Then inside my product class:

```
private SimpleDoubleProperty prodPrice;

 public void setprodPrice(double value) {
    prodPriceProperty().set(value);
}

public Double getprodPrice() {
    return prodPriceProperty().get();
}

public SimpleDoubleProperty prodPriceProperty() {
    if (prodPrice == null) {
        prodPrice = new SimpleDoubleProperty(this, "prodPrice");
    }
    return prodPrice;
}
```

And my SQL:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM sm_product WHERE productCategory = '" + category + "'";
        ResultSet rs = null;
        // Call readRequest to get the result
        rs = db.readRequest(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String ID = rs.getString("productID");
            String name = rs.getString("productName");
            String desc = rs.getString("productDescription");
            double price = rs.getDouble("productPrice");
```

By the way I am doing it in JavaFX.

Comment: If you need formatting, you need a data type which includes formatting. I suggest using a String property or BigDecimal if it is supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format your double value to formated string using [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

```
String priceString = new DecimalFormat("$##.##").format(price);
```

*Output* -

```
$15.50
```

Comment: Sorry what am I trying to do is change it to display 2 decimal places like currency. For example, $15.50

Comment: Actually it will print two decimal value only, answer updated, better try it. :)

Comment: But it still displayed as 15.5 which is one decimal places.

Comment: @Gwen Try `"$##.00"` to ensure at least 2 digits are shown. The `"$##.##"` ensures at most two digits are shown.

Answer (score 2):

You can format by using `BigDecimal`:

```
double value= 255.956666;

BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println("value=" + bd);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, get the value in the form of String.

```
String price = rs.getString("productPrice");
```

And where-ever you need to display the result display the string and for the calculation part convert it into Double and then use it.

Comment: But what if when create product, the user only enter 15.5. Then if I display using string without converting, it will be displayed as 15.5

Answer (score 0):

You can format the price using NumberFormat :

```
  NumberFormat nf = new NumberFormat() ;
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2) 
    nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2)  


        nf.format(ton_double)
         while (rs.next()) {
                    String ID = rs.getString("productID");
                    String name = rs.getString("productName");
                    String desc = rs.getString("productDescription");
            double priceNF = rs.getDouble("productPrice");

                    double price = Double.valueOf(nf.format(priceNf));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't store your values as `Double`s. `BigDecimal` is the standard type for monetary values.